# Showing image in a DataGridViewImageColumn binding text-field

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a WindowsForm project and in my form I have a `DataGridView` with a `DataGridViewImageColumn` which must show the **status** of the row (enabled/disabled) using an image.

I have a `DataTable` that I bind to my datagrid. In this table there is a column that is the **status** of each row and is a text field.

How can I bind this column to the `DataGridViewImageColumn` showing the right image?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever I have questions on how to do things in a DataGridView I consult Microsoft's FAQ first.

http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc

Typically what I do in that situation is handle the CellFormatting event to set the image based on the value in the cell.

So I would store my images in something like an image list, then have code in CellFormatting like the following:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "status")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString() == "1")
            {
                e.Value = imageList1.Images[1];
            }
            else
            {
                e.Value = imageList1.Images[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @UWSkeletor - (I know the post is old) Won't this code execute 2 times ? Once on the initial cell formatting event and then when the value is set to the image .
So why not do it in the databinding complete event?

Comment: Using the CellFormatting event is a really bad idea although the `if (e.Value != null)` probably fixes the worst issues...