# add image in each datagrid gwt cell

Tags: image, datagrid, datagridview

How to add image in each cell of datagrid table.?

suppose if returned value is 1 then i want to add one green icon in that column?

so how to achieve this?

please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageCell or ImageRssourceCell:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#available

In getValue() method you specify which image you want to be displayed based on some conditions. Or return null to display nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[Showing image in a DataGridViewImageColumn binding text-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789466/showing-image-in-a-datagridviewimagecolumn-binding-text-field/9790368#9790368)

Whenever I have questions on how to do things in a DataGridView I consult Microsoft's FAQ first.

http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc

Typically what I do in that situation is handle the CellFormatting event to set the image based on the value in the cell.

So I would store my images in something like an image list, then have code in CellFormatting like the following:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "status")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString() == "1")
            {
                e.Value = imageList1.Images[1];
            }
            else
            {
                e.Value = imageList1.Images[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```