# How to show unbound columns in a bound DataGridView using c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which i am populating as shown below.This DataGridView  has 7 columns, where 1st, 4th & 6th columns respectively would be unbound and the rest would be bound columns.Now my requirement is

> 1] In column[0], i want to show an autoincrement integer value like "Serial No." 1,2,3.....n
>
> 2] At column[4], i want to show an icon/image from an imagelist.
>
> 3] At column[6], i want to show a Button control

```
      try
        {
            using (FbConnection conLLV = new FbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conLLV.Open();
                using (FbCommand cmdLLV = new FbCommand(sqlQryLLV, conLLV))
                {
                    cmdLLV.Parameters.Add("@t_id", FbDbType.Integer).Value = tid;
                    cmdLLV.Parameters.Add("@mem_id", FbDbType.Integer).Value = mid;
                    cmdLLV.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (FbDataAdapter daLLV = new FbDataAdapter(cmdLLV))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dtLLV = new DataTable())
                        {
                            daLLV.Fill(dtLLV);

                            dgSSW.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                            dgSSW.ColumnCount = 7;

                            //At Column[0] ->a Serial No column

                            dgSSW.Columns[1].Name = "subsec_name";
                            dgSSW.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Sub Section Name";
                            dgSSW.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "subsec_name";

                            dgSSW.Columns[2].Name = "rt_correct_ans";
                            dgSSW.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Correct Answer";
                            dgSSW.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "rt_correct_ans";

                            dgSSW.Columns[3].Name = "rt_your_ans";
                            dgSSW.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Your Answer";
                            dgSSW.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "rt_your_ans";

                            //At Column[4] ->an Image column

                            dgSSW.Columns[5].Name = "q_r_difficulty";
                            dgSSW.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Difficulty Level";
                            dgSSW.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "q_r_difficulty";

                            //At Column[6] ->a column having a Button control

                            dgSSW.DataSource = dtLLV;
                        }//data table closed and disposed here
                    }// data adapter closed and disposed up here
                 }// command disposed here
            }//connection closed and disposed here
        } 
        catch (FbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("LLV--" + ex.Message);
        }
```

How can i achieve my requirements please advise using codes.I have searched the internet but the solutions given does not match my requirements.

Comment: wow! no comment on my question yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible solution by steps:

0] set datasource

```
dgSSW.DataSource = dtLLV;
```

1] row numbers: add column for them and apply cell formatting

```
var col0 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "#", Name="RowNum", 
        ReadOnly = true, 
        Width = 10
    };
dgSSW.Columns.Insert(0, col0);

dgSSW.CellFormatting += GridCellFormatting;

private void GridCellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgSSW.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "RowNum")
    {
        e.Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

2] image column:

```
var col3 = new DataGridViewImageColumn { HeaderText = "Pic", Name = "Pic" };
dgSSW.Columns.Insert(4, col3);

// set image for a cell
dgSSW["Pic", 0].Value = Resources.add;
```

3] buttons column with clicks handling

```
var col7 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Proceed", Name = "Action", 
        Text = "+",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true
    };
dgSSW.Columns.Add(col7);

dgSSW.CellContentClick += GridCellContentClick; 

private void GridCellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgSSW.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Action")
    {
        MessageBox.Show((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString());
    }
}
```

**update**: since you don't use `AutoGenerateColumns` and create all columns manually, you can create all col0, col3, col7 and after that set `DataSource`

Comment: ok thanks for your reply @Ash.I will implement your suggestions.But i have  question though, What about the data bound columns? Should i leave them just as they are?

Comment: Hey @Ash if you are still there can you please tell me how do i show value of Bound invisible field data in the button click event of column 7

Comment: @gomeshmunda, event arg data includes `RowIndex`. so in `GridCellContentClick` follow one of the following ways: `var invisVal = dgSSW["InvisCol", e.RowIndex].Value;` OR `var data = dgSSW.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView; var invisVal = data["InvisCol"];`

Comment: you are a genius.it works like a charm!.One thing i would like to mention to you though, in column3, the image column, the image is not shown when i use (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.cross; or  imgList.Images[0];

Comment: @gomeshmunda, you can try set image for column at once `var col3 = new DataGridViewImageColumn { HeaderText = "Pic", Name = "Pic", Image = ... };`; or maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789466/showing-image-in-a-datagridviewimagecolumn-binding-text-field; i tried `dgSSW["Pic", 0].Value = Resources.add;` in Form.Load handler successfully

Comment: HeaderText = "Pic", Name = "Pic", Image = ... This part worked. Thanks @ASh